# Woocommerce custom price measurement

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I have a product based on weight measurement. I save prices in serialize as a post meta and I can not enter the sale and regular price. For displaying it on single product page I use my first index[0] price of meta box to display price on front end. But once a user enter quantity they change price according to rule (pricing table). How I can change the price now for specific quantity.

I use woocommerce_get_price to show a product price on page. What I can do if some one change quantity and I need to change price as base on rule (pricing table).

Thanks in advance.